# Laboratory fixed-vector components

Tags: vectors

What are laboratory fixed-vector components? I have an effective Hamiltonian derived from a 40-something year-old Chemical Physics paper. The article mentions the term laboratory fixed-vector components. I presume that the suggestion here is that when you go about computing the dot product of two vectors, you must consider their components to be fixed, i.e. non-varying, in space.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I guess this might be an old way of talking about [lab-frame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laboratory_frame_of_reference) - as opposed to molecular-frame or centre-of-mass frame